# Call my.exe from powershell

Tags: powershell

I am calling an executable from powershell using:

```
  $MyApp = .\MyApp_2.3.64.exe
  #$MyApp = ".\MyApp_2.3.64.exe"
  #$MyApp = '.\MyApp_2.3.64.exe'      
  $Options = "transform data.csv -output out -verbose $user"

  $MyApp transform data.csv -output out -verbose $user
  $MyApp $Options

  # Works
  .\MyApp_2.3.64.exe transform data.csv -output out -verbose $user
```

Based on below answer it works with:

```
  & $MyApp transform data.csv -output out -verbose $user
```

But it fails when I do:

```
  $options = "transform data.csv -output out -verbose $user"
  # $options = 'transform data.csv -output out -verbose $user'
  & $MyApp $options
```

How do I pass options etc. to the executable in a parameter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$exe =  ".\MyApp_2.3.64.exe"
& $exe transform data.csv -output out -verbose
```

Or `.$exe`

It didn't work before as you `$variable` will just print value of a variable and to "execute" a variable you need to prefix it with a special character (either `&` or `.`).
Now, with parameters you are doing the same again, you just pass a string variable which holds all of your parameters. You need to pass array of parameters, like:

```
$exe =  ".\MyApp_2.3.64.exe"
$params = ("transform", "data.csv", "-output", "out", "-verbose")
& $exe $params
```

Comment: Shouldn't you use the Invoke-Command or Invoke-Expression cmdlet? Also you could explain why his version does not work. Please enrich your answer a little bit. Thank you.

Comment: much better. Thank you.